# How do I step through JavaScript code line by line without placing breakpoints on each line in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This might be a silly question, but I can't find out how to do this without placing breakpoints everywhere.

Ideally what I want to do is put one breakpoint at the beginning of a function, then when it breaks, press a short-cut key to the next line, then the next, and so on. But every time I do this, it skips a million lines until it meets the next breakpoint.

How do I avoid this? Am I missing something?

Comment: `press a short-cut key to the next line` Which short-cut keys? have you gone through [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: `F10` makes it move 1 step forward but doesn't enter functions. `F11` enters the next function. `shift + F11` skips the next function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> :

[image]

Note that it doesn't always work very well when you're iterating over minified javascript rebuilt using source maps.

[Complete documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: I think he's rather looking for `F10` shortcut